# Result of changing nonlocal variable in a inner function after multiple calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, closures

I was messing around with in python to get an handle on using inner functions, closures and the like and I came across what seems to me weird behavior.

When I tried changing the value of an outer function variable in the inner function I expected either to keep track of changes made by subsequent call to the closure or have no change at all.

```py
def a():
  x = 0
  def b():
    nonlocal x 
    print(x)
    x =+ 1
  return b

c = a() 
c()
c()
c()
c()
c()
```

In my case I was expecting to get either get 1,2,3,4,5 or just 0 from every call if I could modify the variable and if the change persisted or not.

But when I ran the code I got:

```
0
1
1
1
1
```

And I can't figure out why it changes, but only once. Can any one shed some light?

Comment: `x =+ 1` should be `x += 1` otherwise you are just assigning 1 to x every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `+` in wrong place

```
x =+ 1
```

means

```
x = +1
x =  1
```

not

```
x += 1
```

So you don't add `1` to `x` but you always set `1`

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Kinda embarrassing the time I spent trying to figure it out thinking it was a language quirk and it was just a dumb typo.